# How to receive an array as member of an input parameter of a GraphQL service?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

Given this schema:

```
input TodoInput {
  id: String
  title: String
}

input SaveInput {
  nodes: [TodoInput]
}

type SavePayload {
  message: String!
}

type Mutation {
  save(input: SaveInput): SavePayload
}
```

Given this resolver:

```
type TodoInput = {
  id: string | null,
  title: string
}

type SaveInput = {
  nodes: TodoInput[];
}

type SavePayload = {
  message: string;
}

export const resolver = {
  save: (input: SaveInput): SavePayload => {
    input.nodes.forEach(todo => api.saveTodo(todo as Todo));
    return { message : 'success' };
  }
}
```

When I sent this request:

```
mutation {
  save(input: {
    nodes: [
      {id: "1", title: "Todo 1"}
    ]
  }) {
    message
  }
}
```

**Then the value for `input.nodes` is `undefined` on the server side.**

Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Useful info:

- The mutation works properly with scalar values (such as String as input and return)
- I'm using typescript, express and express-graphql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make changes in the `key` in the resolver,

```
export const resolver = {
  save: (args: {input: SaveInput}): SavePayload => {
    args.input.nodes.forEach(todo => api.saveTodo(todo as Todo));
    return { message : 'success' };
  }
}
```